# How to setup the JAVA_HOME at the ubuntu startup

Tags: linux, java

I want to set it at startup in Ubuntu. Currently I have to manually set it after starting up.

Answer (score 5):

You can add it to the /etc/environment file, making it part of every user's environment.

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/"`

To apply this change while the system is still running, use `source /etc/environment`.

Recommended reading: [Enviroment Variables - Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Quotes are superfluous.

Comment: @userunknown quotes aren't necessary, but make it easier for humans to read.